# VS 2017 Community support for custom CodeTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to get custom CodeTemplates working in VS2017 Community edition without much luck.  I've copied the %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding
files to CodeTemplates/ in my proj, tweaked the templates but I don't see any changes.  I've customized the templates in prior vers of VS.  Is it not supported in VS2017 Community Edition?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Same issue using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. The scaffolding dialog does not seem to target my CodeTemplates folder in the root of my MVC Core project. I went and modified one of the templates in %Program Files% and I still did not see any changes in the resulting code. Not sure where VS is getting the templates from or how to change where VS looks.

Answer (score 0):

It works well in Visual Studio 2017. And yes that's the right folder you are looking at. You must copy the files as you did already and make sure to delete all the .vb.t4 if you are using c# as language from the CodeTemplates folder and vice-versa.

One more suggestion is to check and tweak the right template, since it has got withContext, withAction, Empty, etc...

**EDIT** : 
Also when scaffolding, try to add -Verbose to the command, it'll tell you from where the templates are picked.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView